# Missing total when tag is not URL-encoded

Tags: support, api

When trying to get a list of questions for the C# tag, the total field was missing. Tried with Python tag and the total was included.

[/2.2/questions?order=ASC&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow.com&pagesize=1&page=1&tagged=c#](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=ASC&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow.com&pagesize=1&page=1&tagged=c#&filter=!9_bDE.BDp)

[/2.2/questions?order=ASC&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow.com&pagesize=1&page=1&tagged=python](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=ASC&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow.com&pagesize=1&page=1&tagged=python&filter=!9_bDE.BDp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL needs to be URL-encoded such that c# becomes c%23. Then total appears in the results.

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=ASC&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow.com&pagesize=1&page=1&tagged=c%23&filter=!9_bDE.BDp
```

```
{"items":[{"tags":["c#","floating-point","type-conversion","double","decimal"],"owner":{"reputation":1787,"user_id":8,"user_type":"registered","profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/c7ec7dec48168d2a7d792e2b0acc78d1?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG","display_name":"Eggs McLaren","link":"https://stackoverflow.com/users/8/eggs-mclaren"},"is_answered":true,"view_count":56467,"protected_date":1442965259,"accepted_answer_id":7,"answer_count":14,"community_owned_date":1351701767,"score":713,"last_activity_date":1614310275,"creation_date":1217540572,"last_edit_date":1614310275,"question_id":4,"content_license":"CC BY-SA 4.0","link":"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/how-to-convert-a-decimal-to-a-double-in-c","title":"How to convert a Decimal to a Double in C#?"}],"has_more":true,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":263,"total":1472602}
```